# Component for route must be a React component

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to make an app with React native and Expo. Im trying to make a navigation from my Profiel.js to ChoosePhoto.js. When im opening the app on my android emulator i'm getting the error "The component for route ProfielS must be a React component.

the navigator

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import ProfielScreen from '../screens/Profiel';
import PhotoScreen from '../screens/ChoosePhoto';

const ProfielNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    ProfielS: ProfielScreen,
    PhotoS: PhotoScreen

});

export default createAppContainer(ProfielNavigator);
```

my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';

import ProfielNavigator from './navigation/ProfielNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
     <ProfielNavigator />
  );
};
```

my profiel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Fragement } from 'react-native';

export class GebruikerScherm extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      gebruikerId: 2,
      currentPerson: {},
    }
  }

  getData = () => {
    return fetch('(my ip adress)/gebruiker/id?gebruikerId=' + this.state.gebruikerId, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ currentPerson: responseJson });
        console.log(this.state.currentPerson);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {

      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Gebruiker: {this.state.currentPerson.gebruikerID} </Text>
        <Text> Gebruiker: {this.state.currentPerson.gebruikerNaam} </Text>
        <Text> Gebruiker: {this.state.currentPerson.biografie} </Text>

        </View>

      );
    };

};


 export const ProfielScreen = props =>{
     return(
         <View style={styles.container}>
             <Button title="Profielfoto" onPress={() => {
             props.navigation.navigate({
               routeName: 'PhotoS'
              });
             }} />
         </View>
       );
   };


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      marginTop: 200,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }
  });
```

Choosephoto.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';

const ChoosePhotoScreen = props =>{
  return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title="Profielfoto" onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({
            routeName: 'PhotoS'
           });
          }} />
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default ChoosePhotoScreen;
```

I expect my profiel.js page with a button. With the onpress action i want to go from profiel.js to choosephoto.js but the page wont even load.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in the way you bring in objects.

The object you are trying to use is `export` only. Not `export default`

**your profiel.js**

```js
    export const ProfielScreen = props =>{
         return(
             <View style={styles.container}>
                 <Button title="Profielfoto" onPress={() => {
                 props.navigation.navigate({
                   routeName: 'PhotoS'
                  });
                 }} />
             </View>
           );
       };
```

**your  Choosephoto.js**

```js
...
export default ChoosePhotoScreen;
```

**Usage**

```js
import { ProfielScreen }  from '../screens/Profiel';
import ChoosePhotoScreen as PhotoScreen from '../screens/ChoosePhoto';
...
const ProfielNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    ProfielS: ProfielScreen,
    PhotoS: PhotoScreen

});
```

**Example**

> `import React from 'react'`

This essentially says "find the default export from the react module and import that as a constant that I want to call `React`."

> `import { React } from 'react'`

This says "find the export from the react module which is explicitly named React, and import that here as a constant that I want to call `React`."

Answer (score -2):

in profiel.js add default keyword to export :

```
export default  class GebruikerScherm extends React.Component {...
```

and also recheck all related paths in imports of screens.